# Bamboo JDK 14 capabilities

Tags: bamboo

I might be doing wrong, but I'm trying to set up my Bamboo instance with one agent that's able to build JDK 14 projects.

In order to achieve that, I took the following steps:

1. Removed all JDK 8 capabilities from the *Server capabilities* page (*JDK*, *JDK 1.8* and *JDK 1.8.0_252*);
2. Created one local agent at the *Agents summary* page;
3. Added a JDK capability for that agent at the *Agents summary* page (*Java home* pointing to */usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-14.0.0.36-3.rolling.el7.x86_64/*);
4. Added that JDK as a requirement at the *Requirements* tab for the job.

So far, so good, but when I click on *Run Plan*, Bamboo insists on using JDK 8 to build the project.

Checking the following Atlassian help pages ([1](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/capability-289277445.html), [2](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/defining-a-new-custom-capability-289277149.html) and [3](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/defining-a-new-executable-capability-289277164.html)) it seems I'm doing the right thing.

What am I missing here? Thanks for any clues.

PS: I also tried adding JDK 14 as a server capability at the *Server capabilities* page, but I get the same results.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I still don't know if I'm doing it right, but I solved:

1. Added an executable capability called *javac* pointing to */usr/lib/jvm/java-14/bin/javac*.
2. Changed the JDK capability to point to */usr/lib/jvm/java-14*.

Now, in my tasks, I can refer to them as *${bamboo.capability.system.builder.command.javac}* and *${bamboo.capability.system.jdk.JDK}*, respectively.